# Requisição Http, com Certificado x509

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, http-request, certificado-digital

Bom dia,

Ao acessar o seguinte link : 

"https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/downloadNFe.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=&a=mOEyESJIJwMoSf9GhwkJRg7glhHoU0omjiV+4HmZZHwvpF4c9ivAFcAF04DQk1fb"

O site, automaticamente , chama a tela para a seleção do certificado digital.

Assim que confirmado o certificado, ele baixa um arquivo, sem precisar clicar em nenhum botão posterior...

Precisava fazer isso em background na maquina do meu cliente que possui esse certificado..

Logo estou procurando uma forma de passar o certificado x509 (A1 ou a3 com a senha) para a requisição de forma que o site já passe direto para o download do arquivo, e eu consiga pega-lo na programação via c#

Já tentei com WebBrowser ( Não identifiquei uma forma de passar o certificado para a requisição no webbrowser)

Tentei também via POST ( Que acredito ser a forma errada, já que não se trata de um webservice, e sim de um site que responde automaticamente a escolha do certificado)

Buscando uma luz...

Obs: Já tentei com o SELENIUM, porem dessa forma teria que ter interação na tela, e tudo tem que acontecer em background na maquina do cliente que possui o certificado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esse exemplo que eu coloquei importe o seu arquivo certificado.pfx para a raiz do seu projeto.

Não esqueça de setar nas propriedades do certificado.pfx (clicar com botão direito e selecionar propriedades) na opção de "Copiar para diretório de saida" deixe como Copiar Sempre

[image: Propriedades certificado.pfx]

```
public class SeuController : Controller
    {
        static readonly string senhaCertificado = "SuaSenha";

        public async Task<IActionResult> AcessarFazenda()
        {

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("certificado.pfx", senhaCertificado));

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/downloadNFe.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=&a=mOEyESJIJwMoSf9GhwkJRg7glhHoU0omjiV+4HmZZHwvpF4c9ivAFcAF04DQk1fb");

                if (httpResponse.Content != null)
                {

                    //aqui você pode pegar o conteudo da requisição e salvar o arquivo ou devolver ele para a tela para download do usuário
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Não sei se contempla tudo o que você quer porém isso realiza a conexão através do certificado.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Se precisar de mais algum detalhe pode me perguntar. O seu arquivo vai ser disponibilizado para download ou vai salvar em algum diretório ?

Answer (score 0):

- Caso você precisar dos dados em string, voce pode usar assim:

```
X509Certificate newCert = new X509Certificate(certData);
string StringCertificate= newCert.ToString(true);
```

- Caso você precise do byte array , faça desta forma

```
byte[] certData = newCert .Export(X509ContentType.Cert, "password");
```

Através do byte, você pode fazer várias coisas inclusive um export.